# D3 tooltip display on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, tipsy

I am using [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/) to generate tooltips of SVG circles generated though D3. My code is taken right from [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/ilyabo/1373263). Using this code, my tooltips show just fine when I hover over my circle objects:

```
$('.circles').tipsy({ title: 'My tooltip text' })
```

Is there a way to make tooltips show on page load rather than hover? I have tried using `show`, but this does not seem to work:

```
$('.circles').tipsy({ title: 'My tooltip text' })      // show tips on hover
$('.circles').tipsy('show')                            // show tips on page load?
```

Getting tipsy to show tooltips on page load seems possible in theory [based on this example question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12443762/how-do-i-show-tipsy-tooltip-on-load-and-keep-it-shown); however, I can't figure out how to manipulate D3 to make this logic work. How can I make my tooltips show on page load and on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strangely - tipsy does not work well with a selector for each of these circles, so had to use JQuery `each` function to get it to work. You also have to set the option `trigger: 'manual'` in tipsy.

```
$('.circles').each(function() {
   $(this).tipsy({ 
    trigger: 'manual',
    gravity: 'w', 
    html: true, 
    title: function() {
      return 'My tooltip text'; 
    }
   });

   $(this).tipsy('show');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this did not work. My tooltips appear on hover, but not on page load.

Comment: So strange. With your new code, the JQuery selections are working properly, but I still do not get tooltips showing up on page load?